# How to install the RGL for the latest version of GF?

Tags: gf

May I please ask you how to install the RGL for the latest version of GF on Mac OS system? I have tried to follow the GFSS2021 courses, but I didn't find the solution.
Hi,Inariksit, I just tried these methods in Github, but I failed, I chose to run the setup.sh file in one of my desktop file in terminal, and I add the Languages.csv file to the same file, but I don't understand the error:

- Pass the --dest=... flag to this script
- Set the GF_LIB_PATH environment variable
- Compile & install GF from the gf-core repository (must be in same directory as gf-rgl) If I don't misunderstand, I should choose one of these methods, but I don't know how to install this RGL still, and I am stuck here.[image]

I have tried your method, adding the GF_LIB_PATH into the file of .bash_profile, but still I can't run the ConstructionChi.gf file. Could you please help me to see whether the way I add the path is correct?

[image]

Comment: You can install RGL here https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-rgl , following the instructions on the README. If you run into any trouble, just ask again!

Comment: As for ConstructionChi.gf not working: note that all the files on GF_LIB_PATH are compiled GF files, i.e. *.gfo. So you need to do `gf ConstructionChi.gfo` insteead.

Comment: As for the "Unable to find: <path>", see point 4.1 in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are complete steps how to install the RGL from source. It assumes that you have GF already installed

#### 1. Choose a folder on your computer where you want the compiled RGL to be

The compiled RGL can be **anywhere you want**. Once you have chosen the path, you won't need to type it in the future.

Let's suppose for the sake of example, that the path is `/Users/mlamp/rgl_compiled`.

#### 2. Set an environment variable called `GF_LIB_PATH`

I recommend setting up the environment variable GF_LIB_PATH instead of the other methods (e.g. passing a path to the installation script in a flag), because you will need to set up GF_LIB_PATH anyway, if you want to access the RGL from any directory in your computer.

##### 2.1 Setting up an environment variable

In your home directory (where you are in the screenshot), do you have a file called `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.zprofile`, `.zshrc` or `.zshenv`? Or any other file whose name starts with a dot, and contains one or more lines that look like `export SOMETHING_ALL_CAPS=/some/path/on/your/computer`.

If you have already one of those files, just open it in a text editor and add the following line among the rest of the `export FOO=bar` lines:

```
$ export GF_LIB_PATH=/Users/mlamp/rgl_compiled
```

(Of course, using whatever path you actually want to use.)

If you don't have any of the files, you can create a file called `.profile` (the dot is important!) under your home directory, and put that line, `export GF_LIB_PATH=/Users/mlamp/rgl_compiled`, in there.

##### 2.2 Activate the environment variable for the current session

Now if you only put that line in your `.*profile` file, it isn't running yet. Those files are doing their thing every time the system is started. To make sure it takes action now, you can either

- also type `export GF_LIB_PATH=/Users/mlamp/rgl_compiled` on the command line and continue from there, or
- close your terminal and open a new one.

After you've done one of these, proceed to the next step.

#### 3. Install the RGL

Now you have set up your GF_LIB_PATH, so you can go back to the gf-rgl repository and install the RGL. If you have Make, the easiest way is this:

```
$ make install
```

I recommend using the Makefile: it's a wrapper for the 3 different installation methods, and it tries them all until one succeeds, so you don't have to know which one works
for your computer. (But if you don't have Make, then you need to either get Make, or try the different scripts, `Setup.sh` or `Setup.bat` on Windows.)

#### 4. Test if it worked

Now you can go to any other directory, and try to run GF. Try for example

```
$ gf alltenses/LangEng.gfo
```

If it succeeds, then it means that the `$GF_LIB_PATH` is working correctly. If it didn't succeed, the error messages you are getting are important diagnostic methods.

##### 4.1 Wrong path

If you get an error that looks like follows:

```
Unable to find:
 /usr/local/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.6.5/gf-3.11.0/lib/alltenses/LangEng.gfo
```

This means that your system thinks that GF_LIB_PATH is `/usr/local/share/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.6.5/gf-3.11.0/lib/` and not the path you (tried to) set up.

Some things to try from here:

- Check if the GF_LIB_PATH is actually set or not, by doing this in your terminal (any directory):

```
$ echo $GF_LIB_PATH
```

If you get the wrong path, or get nothing, then this means you didn't succeed setting up the environment variable earlier. I'd suggest just to close all terminal windows and open a new terminal, and check again `echo $GF_LIB_PATH`. If this still doesn't work, could it be that the line is in the wrong file? For instance, if you have zshell but put it in a `.bashrc` file or something.

##### 4.2 Right path but no files

If you get an error message that includes the path you have set up, then probably something went wrong with the RGL installation. You can inspect the contents of the path as follows:

```
$ ls $GF_LIB_PATH
```

You should see there a bunch of *.gfo files, or three directories by names `alltenses`, `prelude` and `present`, all three full of * .gfo files.

If this is not the case, go back to step 3, and report what you get for output.

Comment: Good news! I have tried another way to install the RGL, I download the binary package of RGL from the install page of GF, and by adding these files to my GFtest file, finally I got the success! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to hear! If you ever have more questions about GF, just ask another question here on Stack Overflow, or you can also search https://groups.google.com/g/gf-dev to see if someone has had the same issue. In addition, this blog post https://inariksit.github.io/gf/2018/08/28/gf-gotchas.html contains a few common gotchas and weird errors people often get with GF.